# Populating a button array with dynamic button text only work if one button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reselect

I learn React and JavaScript and now I have this problem

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-new-content-tag-list-not-populated-error-1xqsb?file=/src/FileEditor.jsx:454-683)

What happens is like this:

In the Codesandbox at FileEditor.jsx: I mock it like this:

```
// Mocking the tag list just to test it
const tagMock = ['11111']; // THIS WORKS WITH ONLY ONE ITEM
// Mocking the tag list just to test it
//const tagMock = ["11111", "22222", "33333"]; // THIS DOES NOT WORK WITH MULTIPLE ITEMS
```

The `tagMock` that works in the first one with only one array value.
The `tagMock` that does not work is the one with 3 values.

(when you star sandbox the `tagMock` with only one array value is use, please change to `tagMock` with 3 array values to see the error)

If you look further down in FileEditor.jsx you see where `tagMock` is use like this:

```
        {tagMock.map((tag) => (
            <div className="tagInput">
              <button
                className="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                disabled={false}
                key={tag}
                type="button"
                // onClick={() => remove(skill)}
              >
                <TagName tag={tag} />
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
```

Every button created in this map loop have it's own `<TagName tag={tag} />`
The `TagName` is a component that is connected to the Redux Store and there
it `selected` (using `reselect`), the store `tags` and then return the tag name only.

The `button` name text is by so dynamically set like this:

[image]

In the image above, the "name2" button text is set" .

The problem is that this does not work if more then 1 button like this:

```
//const tagMock = ["11111", "22222", "33333"]; // THIS DOES NOT WORK WITH MULTIPLE ITEMS
```

The error I get is the `name` is not defend in the tagName.jsx file.

Why does this happen? I understand it's some form of component duplications issue that the `map` loop can't create the `tagName` Component as it should, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

ok I solved it,

WRONG:

state.global.tags.find(tag => tag.id > ownProps.tag);

RIGHT:

state.global.tags.find(tag => tag.id === ownProps.tag);